# Li-Yau gradient estimates on Riemannian manifolds with decaying Ricci curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, heat-equation

I am trying to understand a statement made in the paper ["On gradient estimates for the heat kernel" by B Devyver](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.10015)
below Proposition 1.26. The Li-Yau local gradient estimate says that ; for any $a > 1$ and $x \in B_R(x_0)$ and $t>0$
$$
\frac{|\nabla u|}{u^2} - \frac{a u_t}{u} \leq CR^{-2}a^2 (\frac{a^2}{a^2-1} + \sqrt{K}R) + \frac{na^2K}{2(a-1)} + \frac{na^2}{2t}
$$
for some C>0 depending only on C, where $u$ is a solution of a heat equation on a riemannian manifold $M$ and $-K<0$ is the lower bound on the Ricci curvature on that ball. Below Proposition 1.26 in this paper it is said that this implies that for Riemannian manifolds where the Ricci curvature is decaying quadratically it actually holds
$$
a \frac{|\nabla u|}{u^2} - \frac{ u_t}{u} \leq b (1/t+1/R^2)
$$
for some positive constants $a,b$. I don't understand how to get rid of the constant factor 
$$
\frac{na^2K}{2(a-1)}
$$
because the proof uses a maximum principle and if the maximum is attained in a point very near $x_0$ it isn't affected by the decay of the Ricci curvature.

Comment: Perhaps you should be studying balls centred away from the "origin" of the quadratic decay? For example if you take points $x_R$ at distance $R$ from the origin and apply the estimate on the ball $B_{R/2}(x_R)$, then you should have $K \sim1/R^2.$

Comment: @Anthony Carapetis This works, but if I understand the author correctly, the $R$ comes from the radius of the ball and not the distance to a origin and it should hold even for the origin itself.